# can you set outer HTML in return function of a React component?

Tags: reactjs, mailchimp

The default behavior of the `MailchimpSubscribe` component displays a status alert upon user signup. I want to move this status alert outside of it's position in the DOM so that it shows up at the top of the page.

My code looks like this:

```
import MailchimpSubscribe from "react-mailchimp-subscribe"
import SimpleForm from './SimpleForm.js'

function Info() {
 return (
  <div className="canary">
   <MailchimpSubscribe url={process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL} 
    render={({subscribe, status, message}) => <SimpleForm
     status={status}
     message={message}
     className="form"
     style={{}}
     onSubmitted={formData => subscribe(formData)}
    />
   }/>
  </div>
 );
}

export default Info;
```

To change the default button text, I create my own `SimpleForm.js` component:

```
import React from "react";

// a basic form
const SimpleForm = ({ status, message, className, style, onSubmitted }) => {
  let input;
  const submit = () =>
    input &&
    input.value.indexOf("@") > -1 &&
    onSubmitted({
      EMAIL: input.value
    });

  return (
    <div className={className} style={style}>
      {status === "sending" && <div style={{ color: "blue" }}>sending...</div>}
      {status === "error" && (
        <div
          style={{ color: "red" }}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }}
        />
      )}
      {status === "success" && (
        <div
          style={{ color: "green" }}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }}
        />
      )}
      <input
        ref={node => (input = node)}
        type="email"
        placeholder="Your email"
      />
      <button onClick={submit}>Subscribe</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SimpleForm;
```

How would I modify this return function so that the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }}` part is set on `<div className="canary">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From what I see in component definition you can pass `render` props](https://github.com/revolunet/react-mailchimp-subscribe/blob/master/src/index.js)

```
MailchimpSubscribe.defaultProps = {
  render: ({ subscribe, status, message }) => (
    <SimpleForm
      status={status}
      message={message}
      onSubmitted={formData => subscribe(formData)}
    />
  )
};
```

with [SimpleForm](https://github.com/revolunet/react-mailchimp-subscribe/blob/master/src/SimpleForm.js) and include specific `className` `style`

```
<MailchimpSubscribe url={process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL} 
  render={({subscribe, status, message}) => <SimpleForm
      status={status}
      message={message}
      className="form"
      style={{}}
      onSubmitted={formData => subscribe(formData)}
    />
}/>
```

If you need more customization you can create your own component based on what's inside [SimpleForm](https://github.com/revolunet/react-mailchimp-subscribe/blob/master/src/SimpleForm.js)

Comment: ooooh i saw the render props, but i thought that meant i could only pass in a `subscribe`, `status`, or `message`

Comment: wait this creates a new problem - `<SimpleForm>` isn't a component that i'm using. i see that the mailchimp code uses it, but does that mean i should be able to use it without importing anything else? i've tried installing and importing a couple different similarly named npm packages, but to no avail

Comment: This `Simpleform` component is just an `input` with `button` wrapped with `div` with `onClick` event. You can either style the container with two mentioned methods in answer or make similar component

Comment: when you say "style the container with two mentioned methods" do you mean `input` and `button`? sorry to be dense, i'm just a little confused about how i actually do that

Comment: I meant `className` and `style` prop for `SimpleForm`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand the problem :

#### Question

How do you render data passed as props to `Component A` within `Component B`?

- `MailchimpSubscribe` holds `message` inside of its internal state and passes it as a prop to the results of its `render` function

#### Answer

React aims to only pass data from parents to children in unidirectional data flow,
so the data passed as props to `MailchimpSubscribe` cannot directly be rendered in another component which is not its child

The best way I can think of to circumvent this is to leverage the [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API to create shared state between the `SimpleForm` rendered inside `MailchimpSubscribe` and a `DisplayMessage` rendered elsewhere in your app.

- In a new file `SharedState.js`

  - Create `SharedContext` to allow components to access context
  - Create `SharedProvider` which is a parent that will make the context available to all its children
- In `SimpleForm`

  - Read `SharedContext`
  - Set up an effect to push the `status` and `message` values up to the context. This effect will be called each time those values change.
  - return `null` when the `status` is not null, as you would like to render the `message` elsewhere and hide the form.
- In `DisplayMessage`

  - Read `SharedContext`
  - Use `status` and `message` from `SharedContext` to render your message

### Demo

I put together [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-for-shared-state-cdxve) which illustrates this strategy.

#### References

- React docs for [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)
- React docs for [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Hope that helps! Let me know if there's anything you'd like clarified further